# Highstock and data units : how to specify data unit?

Tags: highcharts, units-of-measurement

It is 00h03, I am sweating hard and I am done.
I am looking for a good soul to give me a hand with Hightcharts.js's Hightstock options.

I have this simple jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hsolatges/p4k7ery7/1/

```
   highstockOptions = {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            animation: false
        },
        navigator: {
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
            baseSeries: 1
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: false
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'REFERENCE'
            }
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Reference',
            data: dataset,
            downsample: {
                threshold: 1000 // 0 disables downsampling
            },
            turboThreshold: 0
        }]
    };
```

My data is an array of arrays of coordinates [x, y]. Full dataset is a 90,000 points from 0 to 60 minutes. I want labels in minutes, ticks in minutes, navigator showing me minutes.

All I would like to do is telling to Highstock that my dataset arguments are in minutes, not dates, not milliseconds. Just minutes!

I have spent hours. And as trivial as it might be, it turns me crazy.

Thanks folks!

Comment: There isn't option like "Hey, my scale is minutes, do this for me". You need to set properly a couple of options: [units](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.units) (set only minutes there), [dataTimeLabelFormats](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) ( to set required format, again, just minute), [navigator.xAxis](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.xAxis) (the same as two previous ones) and [tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.date) may be helpful too.

Comment: @Pawel So desu ne! I understand my mistake now: I did that only for xAxis of the 'chart' key. Not for the Navigator... But I was trying so hard that I get myself lost inside the highcharts options maze. I will try this tomorrow and keep it alive. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PawełFus I am still unable to manage it. I am working on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oz5atn2x/), xAxis for starting.

Comment: Ok, and what/where is the problem? ;)

Comment: @PawełFus So, on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oz5atn2x/), you can see that my arguments are numbers like this one '3.99999995715916' (between 0 and 60, representing minutes). But Highstock, on the xAxis, show it like this: '00:00:00.003'. And that is not good. I whould like to display it like minutes (from 0 to 60) so the point [3.99999995715916, -374.100005574524] should be near the tick '4' (minutes).

On your recommendation, I tried to use units and dateTimeLabelFormats, and restricted them for minutes on the xAxis options.

But this does not work. :/
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: In JS terms, number like: `3.99999995715916` means ~4milliseconds, not ~4minutes. In other words, translate minutes to milliseconds, for example like this: `var ms = minutes * 60 * 1000`.

Comment: @PawełFus Wow that is a tip! I read a lot but never find this info. Ok. So there might be three ways to deal with that: 1) Converting during data's insert in DB. But that I don't want because I want to keep my data as I get it. 2) Converting each of my 100.000 points' arguments on fly. That could be a performance issue... 3) There is maybe a way to tweak how Highcharts deals with that data format. Is there? That could be great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's no such tweak. Anyway, tweak will be nothing more than converting values on the fly... ;) Simple math calculation for 100.000 of points shouldn't be a big deal with modern browsers.